# Check Windows Network Interfaces and enable them if down with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch file/script...Anyway, on my Windows server, I have two interfaces:

1. Interface-1(Local Area Connection 2) has, say,

   - 10.0.77.200/16 and configured with a default gateway
2. Interface-2(Local Area Connection 3) has, say,

   - 10.0.50.200/30 and no default default gateway configured.

I am looking for a simple way to create a simple batch to check these 2 interfaces, if either one or both are down, I want the batch script to re-enable them automatically.

Thanks,
Lenna -

Comment: @echo off 

    :LOOP
    timeout 30
    ping some_dns_IP
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto RESTART_2
    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto CHECK_3
    :RESTART_2
    netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection 2" disabled
    timeout 6
    netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection 2" enabled
    timeout 6
    goto CHECK_3
:CHECK_3

Answer (score 0):

The `netsh interface show interface` command will return information about the state of the interfaces.  Instead of checking to see if one is down, I would just recommend running the [`netsh interface set interface`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770948(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_5) commands to enable them as it will be much easier and won't hurt anything:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection 2" admin = ENABLED
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection 3" admin = ENABLED
```